# Grading key for exam class

Tags: exam

How could I create an automatic grading key for an exam, based on previously defined percentages? If the total points change, I don't want to change the whole grading key, but let TeX do it automatically. My current solution is a bit complicated. Is there a more simple version?

(By grading key I mean a table where the ranges for a certain mark are given, as the figure shows.)

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}

Grading key:


\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lclll}
        \FPeval{\result}{round(0.8*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\numpoints&&5\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(0.6*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(0.8*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&4\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(0.4*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(0.6*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&3\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(0.2*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(0.4*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&2\\
        0&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(0.2*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&1\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
    \question[10] Question 1.
    \question[5] Question 2.
    \question[10] Question 3.
    \question[10] Question 4.
    \question[5] Question 5.
    \question[5] Question 6.
    \question[5] Question 7.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The total number of points is available as `\exam@numpoints`, and one could use pgfmath to divide by 5.  Check out the aux file for what else is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to implement my own command for grading keys. A general and a special command I developed. Here they are:

```
\newcommand{\gradekey}[4]{\begin{tabular}{rcrl>\bfseries l}
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#4*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\numpoints&&5\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#3*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#4*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&4\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#2*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#3*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&3\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#1*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#2*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&2\\
        0&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#1*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&1\\
    \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\defaultgradekey}{%
    \begin{center}\gradekey{0.35}{0.5}{0.75}{0.9}\end{center}
}
```